# Issues loading data into multiple columns in Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble loading my data into divs across 4 columns. As shown below in my code, the data comes from a 'portfolios' array, but when I map in the function body, It shows all the elements in the array in a single column. What I wanted it to show each element across for columns in bigger screens, and single in mobile display. Can you help?

```js
const portfolios = [
    {
        title: "TitleOne",
        description: "This is description one. ",
        image: "images/imgone.png",
        url: "https://urlone.com",
        type: "Web App"
    },
    {
        title: "TitleTwo",
        description: "This is description two.",
        image: "images/imgtwo.png",
        url: "https://www.urltwo",
        type: "Web App"
    },
    {
        title: "TitleThree",
        description: "This is description three",
        image: "../images/imgthree.png",
        url: "https://www.urlthreei.com",
        type: "Web App"
    },
    {
        title: "TitleFour",
        description: "This is description four.",
        image: "../images/tuberdome.png",
        url: "https://www.urlfour.com",
        type: "Web/Mobile"
    },
]
```

```js
portfolios.map((item) =>
  (
  
    <ul class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
      <li class="col-span-1 flex flex-col text-center bg-white rounded-lg shadow divide-y divide-gray-200">
          <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col p-8">
             <img className="w-64 h-32 flex-shrink-0 mx-auto bg-black rounded-t-lg" src={item.image} alt={item.title}/>
              <h3 className="mt-6 text-gray-900 text-sm font-medium">{item.title}</h3>
              <dl className="mt-1 flex-grow flex flex-col justify-between">
              <dt className="sr-only">{item.title}</dt>
              <dd className="text-gray-500 text-sm">{item.description}</dd>
              <dt className="sr-only">Role</dt>
              <dd className="mt-3">
              <span className="px-2 py-1 text-green-800 text-xs font-medium bg-green-100 rounded-full">{item.type}</span>
               </dd>
               </dl>
               </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're creating separate lists for each portfolio item. You'll want to call `portfolios.map` inside the `<ul>` element to generate a list item for each instead.

```js
<ul class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
    {portfolios.map((item) => (    
        <li class="col-span-1 flex flex-col text-center bg-white rounded-lg shadow divide-y divide-gray-200">
            <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col p-8">
                <img className="w-64 h-32 flex-shrink-0 mx-auto bg-black rounded-t-lg" src={item.image} alt={item.title}/>
                <h3 className="mt-6 text-gray-900 text-sm font-medium">{item.title}</h3>
                <dl className="mt-1 flex-grow flex flex-col justify-between">
                    <dt className="sr-only">{item.title}</dt>
                    <dd className="text-gray-500 text-sm">{item.description}</dd>
                    <dt className="sr-only">Role</dt>
                    <dd className="mt-3">
                        <span className="px-2 py-1 text-green-800 text-xs font-medium bg-green-100 rounded-full">{item.type}</span>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```